# How to display or make the cities selectable in address module?

Tags: database

I'd like to set for users on Drupal 9-Website on the registration form and for some content-types a new field "Address". I did activate module "address" and added new field to user profile. Now, on the registration page the user can choose from select-list his country, after that will be displayed the dependent locality, wich the user can choose too from the select list, but the "City"- and "Post code" -fields are just the input-fields, so they are not pre-defined select-lists and the user(s) have to put in this fields the city name and post code manually.

I tried to use the other module "https://www.drupal.org/project/country_state_city", but there was a some error by import the cities, so it's not clear if it usable.

But anyway, what is the problem to make dependent list of cities today? There are many databases of all countries and locations.

Thanks

Comment: The module that you linked to may work; check the issue queue for more information: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/country_state_city?categories=All  If you are still having trouble, you can file an issue there.

Comment: Thanks for Answer, but I'd rather use the core address module. The other one works not correctly: e.g. for Profile-Module. In addition it isn't translated.

Comment: Address doesn't support this out of the box, so you will have to write your own code.  And unless you have a database of cities with a translation of all the cities in all the languages you want in `.po` format, you will also have to prepare the translations yourself.